# 2nd tableview's cellForRowAtIndexPath seems to be interrupting the first's

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table view controller with 2 table views.  I've went through the debugger and am just baffled.  Most of code in cellForRowAtIndexPath is irrelevant I think, but included it just in case.  Number of rows is consistently read as 9, but most of the time, although not all, the else part of the conditional in cellForRowAtIndexPath is only ran 7 times, according to the debugger and print statements. Whats weird is, all 9 cells indeed come out, but the content for the last cell will be the only wrong info.  That wrong info will only be wrong in its field button and field content;  it will always assume field content is nil and have a field button with the label that goes with the 0th row, but its fieldName will be correct.

This is a really weird bug that has kept me up all night, if I can wake up to a great answer from a Vet it will truly make my day.  Thank you!

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if tableView == POCTableView{
        return 3
    } else{
        let ret = propertyDisplayGroups.count
        print("number of rows is \(ret)")
        return ret
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var POCTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var friendFieldsTableView: UITableView!

var testCount = 0
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == POCTableView{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "POCTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! POCTableViewCell
        cell.dateDisplay.text = "12/20/15"
        cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.white : GREY_COLOR
        return cell
    } else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FriendFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! FriendFieldTableViewCell
        let propertyDisplayGroup = propertyDisplayGroups[indexPath.row]
        cell.fieldName.text = propertyDisplayGroup.fieldText
        let friendFields = friend!.fieldsDictionary
        if let fieldContent = friendFields[propertyDisplayGroup.propertyName] as? String{
            cell.fieldContent.text = fieldContent
        } else {
            cell.addFieldButton.setTitle(propertyDisplayGroup.buttonText, for: .normal)
            cell.addFieldButton.isEnabled = true
            cell.addFieldButton.isHidden = false
            cell.fieldContent.isHidden = true
        }
        testCount += 1
        print("testCount \(testCount)")
        return cell
    }
}
```

p.s: In walking through the debugger, the 2nd table will start loading up its rows after the 7th row of this tableview.  And the 8th row never has any issues, despite it not appearing in the debugger!

Comment: can you add some more code of viewDidLoad and also where you reload these tableview's.

Comment: @Joe how would that change anything? As both declarations of `cell` exist within different scopes of the if/else block.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`if tableView == POCTableView{ ... }`

to

`if tableView === POCTableView{ ... }`

`===` is an operator in swift that determines if two objects have the same reference.

Your conditional will be checking the value of `tableView` against the value of `POCTableView` which will always be `false` unless `UITableView` implements the `Comparable` protocol.. which I think it doesn't.

**If this isn't your issue**

I would look into

```
if let fieldContent = friendFields[propertyDisplayGroup.propertyName] as? String{ ... }
```

It's possible that you are trying to access a key in `friendFields` that doesn't exist in which case `fieldContent` will fail and the `else` block will run giving incorrect data for those mysterious blank cells that appear. Which sounds like a plausible cause for your problem.